# Output ACF repeater on frontend user's profile page (created with Ultimate Member)

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Ultimate Member plugin to manage my user directory. I also use Advanced Custom Fields to create some custom fields on the backend of the user's profile page (location: user form > equal > add/edit) which I want to output via shortcode on the profile page of the current user.

This is what I tried:

```
function acf_repeater() {

um_fetch_user( get_current_user_id() ); {

  if( have_rows('repeater_name') ):

    while ( have_rows('repeater_name') ) : the_row();

      the_sub_field('subfield_name');

    endwhile;

  else :

  endif;
  } 
}

add_shortcode('acf_repeater_shortcode', 'acf_repeater');
```

but this doesn't work. Any tips?

Comment: By default `have_rows()` check to see if **current post** has any row. You should pass user ID, in format `"user_{$user_id}"`, as a second parameter.
Take a look at ["Get values from a user"](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user). And don't display anything in your `acf_repeater()`, shortcode function should **return** the text that is to be displayed.

Comment: 3rd party plugin support is [out of scope](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for WPSE. You should seek help from the plugin's official support streams.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution - perhaps it will be helpful for someone in the future... :)

This is function that will create a table similar to the repeater on the backend. In this case 4 columns - can be adjusted and styled as necessary.

```
function acf_repeater() {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
ob_start(); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_name',"user_{$user_id}" ) ): ?>

<table>
   <tr>
    <td>Column 1 header</td><td>Column 2 header</td><td>Column 3 header</td><td>Column 4 header</td>
   </tr>

<?php while ( have_rows('repeater_name', "user_{$user_id}" ) ) : the_row(); 

    // vars
    $var1 = get_sub_field('subfield_1_name');
    $var2 = get_sub_field('subfield_2_name');
    $var3 = get_sub_field('subfield_3_name');
    $var4 = get_sub_field('subfield_4_name');

?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $var1; ?></td><td><?php echo $var2; ?></td><td><?php echo $var3; ?></td><td><?php echo $var4; ?></td>
    </tr>


<?php endwhile; ?>

</table>
<?php else: echo '<span>No data</span>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
}

add_shortcode('acf_repeater_shortcode', 'acf_repeater');`
```